# Change the value selected from autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, typeahead

I am trying to update the value of an input field after the user chooses a selction from autocomplete. I am using typeahead js for autocomplete feature. Here is my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/jLa7x28y/7/

```
<div id="the-basics">
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>
```

Once the user selects a state, I want to update the value of the input field to its short form. Like if the user selects Connecticut, I would like to update the display as CT. I tried using oninput, bind functions on the input tag. It didnt work. can you please help?

Comment: Have you tried using Bloodhound suggestion engine? Instead of returning states as a string array, you can have a list of state objects (stateName and stateCode properties). Using datumTokenizer you can suggest using state name, after your selects a suggestioin you can display code in the input box. This can be set in your "display" property.

You can refer to "Custom Templates" in the examples [link](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/). In datumTokenizer you can give "stateName", where as in display you can give "stateCode". You also can choose template for your suggestion.

Comment: I did try datumTokenizer. But for some reason it didnt work. But I will try again and see if I was missing something. Thanks for your input.